# including separate files with functions

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to figure this question out for a while, and I've searched and searched but nothing I can comprehend well enough.  So my question is, what would be the best way, or how would I go about including separate files in VB.Net, which I can use to call functions and sub procedures?

I've worked some with web design and PHP coding, and I know it's simple to include files, and I'm curious if there is anything similar to that?

Basically I'm building an application that I'd like to have each section of the app separated by multiple files, so when I update anything on it, I can simply go into the file that needs updating and only have that file updated.

I'm hoping to also have these files separate in the folder containing the entire application.  I've looked into using DLL files to store them, but I can't seem to find anything that specifies only importing the DLL file and calling it's functions.

Comment: Make a class and reference ("imports") it.  Each of your subs / functions will need a "shared" declaration.  "Public Shared Sub DoSomething()"

Comment: By the way... what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried adding classes and modules, but they only seem to add into the VB coding.  I'm hoping to have the files separate in a library folder that contains all the files and when I update the application it would only update the files I tell it to.  As in having the application call on separate files, and I've looked mostly into calling a separate DLL file, which seems to be the most popular but nothing I found specifies importing it and calling on it's functions or sub procedures.

Comment: Are you asking how to simply break a program into multiple files or are you asking how to reference external projects/dll's? If the former, then you may want to brush up on Object Oriented Programming and the use/role of classes.

Comment: Something like the PHP method which inserts code from another file is not a feature in VB.NET. While it works (I guess) well for scripting langagues which are sometimes more procedural than OO, it isn't the norm for .NET coders.  Rule of thumb, if your Method is more than 30 lines, break it up into multiple Methods.  From there, organize your code into classes.  It's the backwards way to take a strawman into a real OO project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting a single class to be split across files, you can use PARTIAL...

```
Public Class MainClass

   ...

End Class
```

in a different file...

```
Partial Class MainClass     
   ...

End Class
```

The IDE will see these as a single class. Visual Studio also lets you use multiple dot filenames, so you can have

- MainClass.vb
- MainClass.FunctionSet.vb

Comment: Kind of, but I'm looking to do this in separate files of the entire application, and no just in visual studio.  I want the finished application to have a library that it calls separate files from.

Comment: This is certainly one route, but the OP wasn't very clear as to the context in which they wanted to use the separate files. They are fine in the right context, but I wouldn't recommend building an entire application with nothing but partial classes. To be honest, I feel they should only be used as a tool to help organize extremely complicated classes (and even then, if it's too complicated for one file, maybe it should be a separate class altogether).

Comment: Classes should be in different files.  @user2501947 you ned a walk through book like http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735613745

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you want.  It sounds like you need to add a Class Library project to your solution and then create your classes and methods there.  When compiled, the resulting .dll can than be used in multiple applications if necessary.